# Append d3 svg to current ng-repeat element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would like to append a d3.js pie chart to each li elements generated with ng-repeat.

```
 <ol>
 <li ng-repeat="h in hashtags | orderBy:predicate:reverse | limitTo: limit">
    <div class="hashtag">
       <a ng-click="showTweetsForHashtag(h)">#{{h.Hashtag}}</a>
    </div>
    <div class="frequency">
       {{h.Frequency}} times
    </div>
    <div class="engagement">
       {{h.Engagement}}
       <pie-chart data="h" on-click="showTweetsForHashtag(item)"></pie-chart>
    </div>
 </li>
</ol>
```

My $scope.hashtag is an array of objects containing hashtags engagement properties :

```
[{
   "Favorites": 0,
   "Frequency": 1,
   "Hashtag": "19h30",
   "Replies": 0,
   "Retweets": 1,
   "Engagement":2,
   "tweetId": 615850479952785400
}, {
   "Favorites": 0,
   "Frequency": 1,
   "Hashtag": "80s",
   "Replies": 0,
   "Retweets": 2,
   "Engagement":2,
   "tweetId": [
         616521677275533300,
         617319253738393600
      ] 
}{
   "Favorites": 1,
   "Frequency": 1,
   "Hashtag": "AloeBlacc",
   "Replies": 0,
   "Retweets": 1,
   "Engagement":2,
   "tweetId": 617309488572420100
}, {
   "Favorites": 2,
   "Frequency": 1,
   "Hashtag": "Alpes",
   "Replies": 0,
   "Retweets": 1,
   "Engagement":3,
   "tweetId": 615481266348146700
}]
```

Tanks to the ng-repeat, each time I call the pie-chart directive, I only pass one h object :

```
{
   "Favorites": 2,
   "Frequency": 1,
   "Hashtag": "Alpes",
   "Replies": 0,
   "Retweets": 1,
   "Engagement":3,
   "tweetId": 615481266348146700
}
```

Which I then manually "map" into that format :

```
var mapped = [{
    "label": "Retweets",
    "value": data.Retweets
}, {
    "label": "Favorites",
    "value": data.Favorites
}, {
    "label": "Replies",
    "value": data.Replies
}];
```

In the end, I would like my directive to append the pie to the current `<div class="pie_chart"></div>` (which is generated in the directive template) with the mapped data of the current h object that has been passed. But as [ocket-san](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31264583/2568754) mentionned `d3.select(someElement)` only matches the first element in the DOM.

Here is my directive :

```
.directive('pieChart', ['d3', function(d3) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            data: '=',
            onClick: '&'
        },
        template: '<div class="pie_chart"></div>',
        link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {


            // watch for data changes and re-render
            scope.$watch('data', function(newVals, oldVals) {
                if (newVals) {
                    scope.render(newVals);
                }
            }, true);

            scope.render = function(data) {
                var w = 50, //width
                    h = 50, //height
                    r = data.Engagement / 3, // adapt radius to engagement value
                    color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#77b255", "#ffac33", "#07c"]); //custom range of colors

                // map data to to be used by pie chart directive
                var mapped = [{
                    "label": "Retweets",
                    "value": data.Retweets
                }, {
                    "label": "Favorites",
                    "value": data.Favorites
                }, {
                    "label": "Replies",
                    "value": data.Replies
                }];
                data = mapped;


                // Courtesy of https://gist.github.com/enjalot/1203641

                var vis = d3.select(".pie_chart")
                    .append("svg:svg") //create the SVG element inside the <body>
                    .data([data]) //associate our data with the document
                    .attr("width", w) //set the width and height of our visualization (these will be attributes of the <svg> tag
                    .attr("height", h)
                    .append("svg:g") //make a group to hold our pie chart
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + r + "," + r + ")") //move the center of the pie chart from 0, 0 to radius, radius

                var arc = d3.svg.arc() //this will create <path> elements for us using arc data
                    .outerRadius(r);

                var pie = d3.layout.pie() //this will create arc data for us given a list of values
                    .value(function(d) {
                        return d.value;
                    }); //we must tell it out to access the value of each element in our data array

                var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice") //this selects all <g> elements with class slice (there aren't any yet)
                    .data(pie) //associate the generated pie data (an array of arcs, each having startAngle, endAngle and value properties)
                    .enter() //this will create <g> elements for every "extra" data element that should be associated with a selection. The result is creating a <g> for every object in the data array
                    .append("svg:g") //create a group to hold each slice (we will have a <path> and a <text> element associated with each slice)
                    .attr("class", "slice"); //allow us to style things in the slices (like text)

                arcs.append("svg:path")
                    .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
                        return color(i);
                    }) //set the color for each slice to be chosen from the color function defined above
                    .attr("d", arc); //this creates the actual SVG path using the associated data (pie) with the arc drawing function
            };
        }
    }
}]);
```

The problem is that the instruction

```
var vis = d3.select(".pie_chart")
    .append("svg:svg")
```

Appends all the pie charts to the first div with the pie_chart class.

I tried changing it to d3.select(iElement) (…) but it didn't work.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks in advance !
Q.

You can see the current output there :
http://i61.tinypic.com/wqqc0z.png

Comment: The problem is that d3.select('.pie_chart') selects the first element matching such class in the body, not within your directive template. Something like `d3.select(element[0]).append('svg')` should work.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `d3.select('.pie_chart')` selects the first element matching such class in the body, not within your directive template. To achieve this, you should use the `element` object provided within the `link` function. In your case:

```
var vis = d3.select(element[0]).select(".pie_chart").append("svg")...
```

I have created a simplified [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jarandaf/ayop3fkx) trying to show this.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Its as simple as restricting to element[0]. Thanks! provides beautiful separation of each repeated item

Answer (score 2):

When we using `Angularjs` and `d3js` together we’ll need to make updating the `d3.select('body')` selection to be relative to the directive using
`d3.select(element[0])` instead of the entire DOM. The reason we have to use `element[0]` instead of just element is because element “is” a jQuery
wrapped selection and not an ordinary DOM object. Doing `element[0]` gives us just the plain old DOM element. (I say “is” in quotes because it’s technically a jqlite wrapped DOM element. jqlite is essentially a slimmed down version of jQuery.)

So you need to update your Code to:

```
.directive('pieChart', ['d3', function(d3) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        data: '=',
        onClick: '&'
    },
    template: '<div class="pie_chart"></div>',
    link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {


        // watch for data changes and re-render
        scope.$watch('data', function(newVals, oldVals) {
            if (newVals) {
                scope.render(newVals);
            }
        }, true);

        scope.render = function(data) {
            var w = 50, //width
                h = 50, //height
                r = data.Engagement / 3, // adapt radius to engagement value
                color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#77b255", "#ffac33", "#07c"]); //custom range of colors

            // map data to to be used by pie chart directive
            var mapped = [{
                "label": "Retweets",
                "value": data.Retweets
            }, {
                "label": "Favorites",
                "value": data.Favorites
            }, {
                "label": "Replies",
                "value": data.Replies
            }];
            data = mapped;


            // Courtesy of https://gist.github.com/enjalot/1203641
            //Part need Update
            var vis = d3.select(iElement[0])
                .append("svg:svg") //create the SVG element inside the <body>
                .data([data]) //associate our data with the document
                .attr("width", w) //set the width and height of our visualization (these will be attributes of the <svg> tag
                .attr("height", h)
                .append("svg:g") //make a group to hold our pie chart
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + r + "," + r + ")") //move the center of the pie chart from 0, 0 to radius, radius

            var arc = d3.svg.arc() //this will create <path> elements for us using arc data
                .outerRadius(r);

            var pie = d3.layout.pie() //this will create arc data for us given a list of values
                .value(function(d) {
                    return d.value;
                }); //we must tell it out to access the value of each element in our data array

            var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice") //this selects all <g> elements with class slice (there aren't any yet)
                .data(pie) //associate the generated pie data (an array of arcs, each having startAngle, endAngle and value properties)
                .enter() //this will create <g> elements for every "extra" data element that should be associated with a selection. The result is creating a <g> for every object in the data array
                .append("svg:g") //create a group to hold each slice (we will have a <path> and a <text> element associated with each slice)
                .attr("class", "slice"); //allow us to style things in the slices (like text)

            arcs.append("svg:path")
                .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
                    return color(i);
                }) //set the color for each slice to be chosen from the color function defined above
                .attr("d", arc); //this creates the actual SVG path using the associated data (pie) with the arc drawing function
        };
    }
}
}]);
```

When you update your code the `directive('pieChart')` function dynamically will select `<pie-chart/>` tag. if you have specific class, update your code to:

```
   var vis = d3.select(iElement[0]).select(".pie_chart")
```

**Update 1**

You need to add `$index` to `ng-repeat` because:

> What Angular is telling us is that every element in an `ng-repeat` needs to be unique. However,
>   we can tell Angular to use the elements index within the array instead to determine uniqueness by adding track by `$index`.

```
 <ol>
   <li ng-repeat="h in hashtags track by $index" | orderBy:predicate:reverse | limitTo: limit">
<div class="hashtag">
   <a ng-click="showTweetsForHashtag(h)">#{{h.Hashtag}}</a>
</div>
  <div class="frequency">
   {{h.Frequency}} times
  </div>
  <div class="engagement">
       {{h.Engagement}}
   <pie-chart data="h" on-click="showTweetsForHashtag(item)"></pie-chart>
  </div>
 </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the answers here to be incorrect in my case.

Jarandaf - was the closest however my solution was to remove the class selector.

and just use the below code:

```
d3.select(element[0]).append('svg')
```

Answer (score 0):

d3.select("element") always selects the first element it finds. For example: suppose you have the following html structure:

```
<body>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p> 
</body>
```

and you would code: d3.select("p").append("svg"), the result is going to be

```
<body>
        <p>
           <svg></svg>
        </p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p> 
</body>
```

You need to use **d3.selectAll(element)**, which will give you a d3 selection with all the items that fit the selector.

edit:

Ok, so i think your final html structure could look something like this:

```
<ol>
 <li ng-repeat="h in hashtags | orderBy:predicate:reverse | limitTo: limit">
    <div class="hashtag">
       <a ng-click="showTweetsForHashtag(h)">#{{h.Hashtag}}</a>
    </div>
    <div class="frequency">
       {{h.Frequency}} times
    </div>
    <div class="engagement">
       {{h.Engagement}}
       <div id="pie_chart">
         <svg> your piechart goes here</svg>
       </div>
    </div>
 </li>
<li ng-repeat="h in hashtags | orderBy:predicate:reverse | limitTo: limit">
    <div class="hashtag">
       <a ng-click="showTweetsForHashtag(h)">#{{h.Hashtag}}</a>
    </div>
    <div class="frequency">
       {{h.Frequency}} times
    </div>
    <div class="engagement">
       {{h.Engagement}}
       <div id="pie_chart">
         <svg> another piechart goes here</svg>
       </div>
    </div>
 </li>
</ol>
```

so suppose that html structure already exists without the  tag (its because i dont know anything about angular or directives :-) ) and you want to append the svg tag and append an  tag to every div with class "pie_chart", you need to do it as following:

```
var piecharts = d3.selectAll(".pie_chart").append("svg");
```

The result will be an html structure like above.

If this is not what you want, then I am sorry, I think i totally misunderstood the question :-)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on that. But I guess that if I do a d3.selectAll(".pie_chart"), all of my <li> elements will be appended with all of the pies, won't they ?     Cheers. Q.

Comment: my pleasure :-). But now you kind of lost me. I ll edit my answer to what I think it is you want to achieve as the final html structure. Only the <li> elements with an element who has the class .pie_chart will be appended with an <svg> tag

Comment: Hmmm, that's not exactly what I had in mind. I'll also edit my question so you can see the problem I face. Cheers. Q.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Gabriel for you answer !

In the meantime, I found a workaround (it may not be a the prettiest, but it works !)

Directive :

```
.directive('pieChart', ['d3', function(d3) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            data: '=',
            max: '@',
            item: '@',
            onClick: '&'
        },
        template: '<div class="pie_chart"></div>',
        link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {


            // watch for data changes and re-render
            scope.$watch('data', function(newVals, oldVals) {
                if (newVals) {
                    scope.render(newVals);
                }
            }, true);

            scope.render = function(data) {
                // Courtesy of https://gist.github.com/enjalot/1203641

                var vis = d3.selectAll(".pie_chart")
                    .each(function(d, i) {
                        if (scope.item == i) {
                            var w = 50, //width
                                h = 50, //height
                                normalized = 50 * (data.Engagement) / (scope.max),
                                r = normalized/2, // adapt radius to engagement value
                                color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#77b255", "#ffac33", "#07c"]); //custom range of colors

                            // map data to to be used by pie chart directive
                            var mapped = [{
                                "label": "Retweets",
                                "value": data.Retweets
                            }, {
                                "label": "Favorites",
                                "value": data.Favorites
                            }, {
                                "label": "Replies",
                                "value": data.Replies
                            }];
                            var vis = d3.select(this)
                                .append("svg:svg") //create the SVG element inside the template
                                .data([mapped]) //associate our data with the document
                                .attr("width", w) //set the width and height of our visualization (these will be attributes of the <svg> tag
                                .attr("height", h)
                                .append("svg:g") //make a group to hold our pie chart
                                .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w/2) + "," + (h/2) + ")") //move the center of the pie chart from 0, 0 to radius, radius
                                .on("click", function(d, i){
                                   return scope.onClick({item: data});
                                });

                            var arc = d3.svg.arc() //this will create <path> elements for us using arc data
                                .outerRadius(r);

                            var pie = d3.layout.pie() //this will create arc data for us given a list of values
                                .value(function(d) {
                                    return d.value;
                                }); //we must tell it out to access the value of each element in our data array

                            var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice") //this selects all <g> elements with class slice (there aren't any yet)
                                .data(pie) //associate the generated pie data (an array of arcs, each having startAngle, endAngle and value properties)
                                .enter() //this will create <g> elements for every "extra" data element that should be associated with a selection. The result is creating a <g> for every object in the data array
                                .append("svg:g") //create a group to hold each slice (we will have a <path> and a <text> element associated with each slice)
                                .attr("class", "slice"); //allow us to style things in the slices (like text)

                            arcs.append("svg:path")
                                .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
                                    return color(i);
                                }) //set the color for each slice to be chosen from the color function defined above
                                .attr("d", arc); //this creates the actual SVG path using the associated data (pie) with the arc drawing function
                        }
                    })
            };
        }
    }
}])
```

HTML

```
<ol>
  <li ng-repeat="h in hashtags | orderBy:predicate:reverse | limitTo: limit">
    <div class="hashtag">
      <a ng-click="showTweetsForHashtag(h)">
        #{{h.Hashtag}}
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="frequency">
      {{h.Frequency}} times
    </div>
    <div class="engagement">
      <pie-chart data="h" max="{{hashtagMaxEngagement}}" item="{{$index}}" on-click="showTweetsForHashtag(item)">
      </pie-chart>
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Thanks everyone for your help !

Q.